# Expander not displaying heading that contains underscore

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF `Expander` header is a text which contains an underscore. Because of the presence of underscore, the heading is not displayed for the `Expander`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF will interpret an underscore as an access key in some controls like a `Label` or even an `Expander`. Pressing the key after the underscore will expand or collapse the `Expander` in this case.

In order to prevent this behavior, use double underscores instead, e.g.:

```
<Expander Header="T__est"/>
```

For more information on access keys, there is a how-to on MSDN for labels.

- [How to: Create a Control That Has an Access Key and Text Wrapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-control-that-has-an-access-key-and-text-wrapping?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)